# Unable to set up a simple LIKE+ignore case query in JPA+spring Data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to return a basic list of cities that start with the given name without success, I have tried all of the following combinations:

1. Using pure JPA keywords in Spring Data:

`List<City> findByNameENStartingWithIgnoreCaseAndAdminDivisionAndCountry( String cityName, AdministrativeDivision administrativeDivision, Country country);`

2. Using LIKE and CONCAT:

`@Query("SELECT c from City c WHERE UPPER(c.nameEN) LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:cityName), '%') AND c.adminDivision = :adminDivision AND c.country = :country")
    List<City> findByNameENStartingWithIgnoreCaseAndAdminDivisionAndCountry(@Param("cityName") String cityName, @Param("adminDivision") AdministrativeDivision administrativeDivision, @Param("country") Country country);`

I am using Spring Boot 2.03, Spring data 2.08 and below my City Entity definition:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="city",
        uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(name = "uniqueCityConstraint", columnNames={"name_en", "country_iso3166_numeric3", "admin_division_id"}))
public class City  extends AbstractBaseEntityId {

    @Column(name="name_en")
    private String nameEN;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_division_id")
    private AdministrativeDivision adminDivision;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country_iso3166_numeric3", nullable=false)
    private Country country;

}
```

and my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:spring
spring.datasource.username = sa

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, none)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

and my CityRepository:

```
package com.billpayments.repository;

import com.billpayments.domain.AdministrativeDivision;
import com.billpayments.domain.City;
import com.billpayments.domain.Country;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {
    @Cacheable(value="cityByNameAdminDivisionIdAndCountryCode", key="#p0 + #p1.id + #p2.iso3166Alpha2")
    City findByNameENIgnoreCaseAndAdminDivisionAndCountry(String name, AdministrativeDivision administrativeDivision, Country country);

    List<City> findByNameENIgnoreCaseAndCountry(String name, Country country);

    @Query("SELECT c from City c WHERE UPPER(c.nameEN) LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(:cityName), '%') AND c.adminDivision = :adminDivision AND c.country = :country")
    List<City> findByNameENStartingWithIgnoreCaseAndAdminDivisionAndCountry(@Param("cityName") String cityName, @Param("adminDivision") AdministrativeDivision administrativeDivision, @Param("country") Country country);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake in my own test case, I wasn't passing the right province, so I just wanted to confirm that actually either of the query methods that I posted works fine.  I personally prefer Option#1 as it involves less code to maintain.